# Extract subset from pandas dataframes ensuring no overlap?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, sampling

Suppose I have 2 Pandas dataframes `df` with `297232 x 122` dimensions and `df_raw` with `840380x122` dimensions. `df` is already a subset of `df_raw`. Both dataframes have the index as `DateTime`. I would like to sample `70%` of values from `df`, and `30%` of values from `df_raw` (can be randomly sampled if need), while ensuring that the sampled dataframe subsets do not have overlaps in terms of indexes.

To be more precise, `df_subset` will have `70%` randomly selected values from `df`, and `df_raw_subset` have `30%` randomly selected values from `df_raw`, but `df_subset` and `df_raw_subset` should not contain overlaps in terms of rows which were sampled, i.e. they should have unique `DateTime` indices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So fist we `sample` from df, since the size is small , when we drop it in the future from another bigger df , we will not have the problem : do not have enough data point to `sample`

```
df_sub=df.sample(frac=0.7, replace=False)
```

Then we drop the index in `df_raw` by `df_sub`

```
n=int(len(df_raw)*0.3)
df_raw_sub=df_raw.drop(df_sub.index).sample(n,replace=False)
```

Comment: Thanks @WeNYoBen for the answer.